# How do I save geolocation data for an HTML5 or trigger.io app for path mapping later?

Tags: html, geolocation, trigger.io

Im creating an app that needs to track the location of the user (with their knowledge, like a running app) so that I can show them their route later.  Should I use HTML5 with some timeout interval to save the coordinates every N seconds and if so, how often should I save the data and how should I save it (locally using local storage or post it to the server?)

Also, what is the easiest way to display the map of where the user has been later?

Has anyone done anything like this before?

Answer (score 2):

The timeout interval for `forge.geolocation` is up to you and the balance of responsiveness of your application.  Also, network traffic is expensive.  So maybe you can buffer... say the last 10 geopositions... and then Http post (or whatever... see Parse below) in bulk?  And since the geo data sounds like temporary device data why would there be a need to persist using `forge.prefs`?  Unless maybe you need to the app to work "offline"?

For permanent storage I would look at [Parse](https://parse.com/docs/) (generous free plan) and their `Parse.GeoPoint` class via their Javascript or REST Api as one possible solution.  They have some nifty methods like (kilometersTo, milesTo, radiansTo) - https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.GeoPoint.html